# Laravel error while running composer install `driver [] is not supported`

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface

I want to run a laravel application cloned from github.

i ran the commands :

```
git clone my-repo-title
```

and

```
composer install
```

but this error happens

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   InvalidArgumentException

  Driver [] is not supported.
```

with this message :

```
105▕
106▕             if (method_exists($this, $driverMethod)) {
107▕                 return $this->{$driverMethod}($config);
108▕             } else {
➜ 109▕                 throw new InvalidArgumentException("Driver [{$config['driver']}] is not supported.");
 110▕             }
    111▕         }
    112▕     }
    113▕
```

What can i do for resolve this problem ? edit my .env file ?

When i do the command `composer update` the same error happens.

What can i do for that ?

Thanks you all

Comment: What file is the error coming from? I see 4 files, relating to logs, file systems, cache, and broadcasting.

Comment: Being line 109, I'm going to guess it's the cache driver, so you'll want to check your settings in `config/cache.php` as well as the `CACHE_DRIVER` in your .env file

Comment: did you create a .env file?  Use .env.example for an idea of what to include

Comment: Hi thanks you all for your answers, the error is from the file CacheManager.php from Illuminate `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager.php`.

Comment: I have create a .env file but not configure it, and the error still remain. Should I change some parameters in the .env file ?